# Upgrading Authorize.net to Akamai

Tags: authorize.net

> Authorize.Net will be upgrading access to the Internet connections
>   that serve our data centers. Instead of allowing direct connections,
>   all Internet traffic will be routed through Akamai, a third-party
>   cloud network service that routes and delivers Internet traffic.
>
> The new Akamai transaction URLs that are available now are:
>
> https://api2.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api
>
> https://api2.authorize.net/soap/v1/Service.asmx
>
> https://secure2.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll

How would I go about upgrading my current system to use these?

```
require_once 'anet_php_sdk/AuthorizeNet.php'; 
    define("AUTHORIZENET_API_LOGIN_ID", $authLogin);
    define("AUTHORIZENET_TRANSACTION_KEY", $authKey);
    //Set to true for test account, set to false for real account
    define("AUTHORIZENET_SANDBOX", false);
    $sale = new AuthorizeNetAIM;
    $sale->amount = $rate;
    $sale->card_num = $ccnumber;
    $sale->exp_date = $ccexpire;
    $sale->card_code = $cccvv;
    $response = $sale->authorizeOnly();
    //If approved, use this for getting the transaction ID.
    if ($response->approved) {
        $transaction_id = $response->transaction_id;


    require_once 'anet_php_sdk/AuthorizeNet.php';
    define("AUTHORIZENET_API_LOGIN_ID", $authLogin);
    define("AUTHORIZENET_TRANSACTION_KEY", $authKey);
    $subscription                          = new AuthorizeNet_Subscription;
    $subscription->name                    = "Monitoring";
    $subscription->intervalLength          = "1";
    $subscription->intervalUnit            = "months";
    $subscription->startDate               = $subStartDate;
    $subscription->totalOccurrences        = "9999";
    $subscription->amount                  = $rate;
    $subscription->creditCardCardNumber    = $ccnumber;
    $subscription->creditCardExpirationDate= $ccexpire;
    $subscription->creditCardCardCode      = $cccvv;
    $subscription->billToFirstName         = $firstname;
    $subscription->billToLastName          = $lastname;

    $request = new AuthorizeNetARB;
    $response = $request->createSubscription($subscription);
    $subscription_id = $response->getSubscriptionId();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Version 1.8.5 of the Authorize.Net SDKs now support the new Akamai endpoints.  You can obtain them here: https://Github.com/authorizenet

Comment: So it's not just a matter of updating the endpoints? There are also relevant code updates to the SDK?

Comment: @meder I went into the SDK and updated all of the URL's and made sure all of my code has updated URL's as well. Most of them are just adding a "2" at the end or something similar.